# Updating Report's destination folder using Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I have a use case where if someone creates Reports and accidently saves it in the Public Reports folder ( in lightning ), that report needs to be saved in his Private Reports folder.This is done to make sure that Public Reports folder is kept clean.

I did some research and found that Report object can only be queried and no DML can be performed.Then, I came across Metadata API.But I am not sure how to do this and what should be my approach to get it done.

How do we update the Report's destination folder to be marked to the created by' Private Reports folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot peek into or move stuff in/ out of a user's Private folder. You can move Reports in and out of folders by manipulating the folder's meta.xml file but this still will not give you access to a user's private folders. Metadata API gives you access to Public folders only (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm).

Hope this answers your question.